# Excel VBA Validation List Error

Tags: vba, excel

I went throught various threads and got several tips on Validation. But still my code is throwing me an error. It could be a silly error but i couldn;t spot it.

```
        Set val1range = projInfo.Range(projInfo.Cells(2, 23), projInfo.Cells(m, 23))     

        With Cells(rowN, 3).Validation
                .Delete
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & val1range

                .IgnoreBlank = True
                .InCellDropdown = True
                .InputTitle = ""
                .ErrorTitle = ""
                .InputMessage = ""
                .ErrorMessage = ""
                .ShowInput = True
                .ShowError = True
        End With
```

I am getting a 1004 error on the line .Add
Application-defined or object-defined error.

Could youplease let me know if i am giving the correct formula?

Comment: What part of the code is causing the error?

Comment: i am getting at .Add line

Comment: I think it could be due to the fact that you .Delete the row and  then reference it straight after. Try calling the Delete Method outside the With Block

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the only error, since the code you posted doesn't define `projInfo`, `m`, or `rowN`, but your Add method is attempting concatenate a string, `"="`, and a range object, `val1Range`.  The default property of Range objects is Value, so in effect you're concatenating `"="` with the value or *content* of the cell instead of its address (which is presumably what you want).

To fix, change this line:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & val1range
```

to this:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:="=" & val1range.Address
```

Comment: the projinfo, m rowN are all defined in previous lines and they all hold vaild values. Just i didn't show them here.. and i am sorry about that. I gave the fix you suggested. Still i am getting the same error.